# how to deserialize json inside list activity

Tags: c#, json, listview, http, xamarin.android

I've been trying to pass data using json http in my list view. but It seems that I cant retrieve any data.. please help :(

here's my class where I deserialize my json.

```
public class MountainsData
{
    string url = "https://ia601507.us.archive.org/10/items/mountainsData/mountainsData.json";

    public static List<Mountain> Mountains = new List<Mountain>();


    public MountainsData()
    {
        Task.Run(() => this.LoadDataAsync(url)).Wait();
    }
    private async Task LoadDataAsync(string uri)
    {
        if (Mountains != null)
        {

            string responseJsonString = null;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    Task<HttpResponseMessage> getResponse = httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await getResponse;

                    responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Mountains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Mountain>>(responseJsonString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string message = ex.Message;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and heres how I call my it..

```
 public class MountainListAct : Activity
{
    private List<Mountain> mMountains;
    private ListView mListView;
    private LinearLayout mContainer;
    private Mountain mt = null;
    private Intent i = null;
    private MountainsAdapter mAdapter;
    private Context context;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);           
            mMountains = MountainsData.Mountains;
            mAdapter = new MountainsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.ml_model, mMountains);
            mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
    }
```

my json file https://ia601507.us.archive.org/10/items/mountainsData/mountainsData.json

I do not know why I dont recieve any data.. please help me :(

my model :

```
public class Mountain
{
    public string MtName { get; set; }
    public int Masl { get; set; }
    public int Difficulty { get; set; }
    public int Island { get; set; }
    public string MtImg00 { get; set; }
    public string MtImg01 { get; set; }
    public string MtImg02 { get; set; }
    public string MtImg03 { get; set; }
    public string MtImg04 { get; set; }
    public string MtImg05 { get; set; }
    public string VidDesc { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc00 { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc01 { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc02 { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc03 { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc04 { get; set; }
    public string ImgDesc05 { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; } 
    public string JumpOff { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Background { get; set; }
    public string Itinerary { get; set; }
    public string Practicalities { get; set; }
    public string Attire { get; set; }
    public string Ttb { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Vid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe 'MountainsData' is null, so you don't enter to http call in `LoadDataAsync`